# What mean of "product online" or offline in magento 2.0?

Tags: product, magento2

What mean of "product online" or offline in magento 2.0 ? 
Please explain this mean of words "product online", if you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Online/offline is the equivalent of `status` (enabled/disabled) from magento 1.
if "offline" is set, it means the product will not appear in the frontend.
If "online" is set it means the product might appear in the website (depending on other factors).

Comment: What's table store this value (and name of column ?) ?

Comment: `catalog_product_entity_int` stores the value. But it's complicated. Read more about [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)